# Sql query where date='2012-10-22' but has more info in database

Tags: sql, date

It is formatted in the database.

```
2012-10-22 07:54:44.277
```

I need it to just filter by the day.

How would i do this?

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Comment: If Oracle TRUNC(datefield) = '12-10-22'  In other RDBMS you could cast the field to just a date which would drop the timestamp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check for a range

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE Date >= '2012-10-22 00:00:00'
AND Date < '2012-10-23 00:00:00'
```